How to make sap.m.Table HeaderToolbar & ColumnHeaders sticky in ScrollContainer with dynamic height
I am using a sap.m.Table with x-entries in my View. The sap.m.Table is surrounded by a sap.m.Panel. I want the ColumnHeaders and HeaderToolbar of the sap.m.Table to continue to be displayed when scrolling, as the table contains many entries.
My current structure is as follows:
<mvc:View
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <Panel headerText="Some other panel" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
        <content>
            <Text text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."/>
        </content>
    </Panel>
    <Panel title="My panel" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
        <content>
            <ScrollContainer vertical="true" height="100%">
                <Table sticky="HeaderToolbar,ColumnHeaders">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <OverflowToolbar>
                            <Text text="My panel"/>
                        </OverflowToolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <columns>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Column 1"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Column 2"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Column 3"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Column 4"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Column 5"/>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                            <Text text="Value 1"/>
                            <Text text="Value 2"/>
                            <Text text="Value 3"/>
                            <Text text="Value 4"/>
                            <Text text="Value 5"/>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                            <Text text="Value 1"/>
                            <Text text="Value 2"/>
                            <Text text="Value 3"/>
                            <Text text="Value 4"/>
                            <Text text="Value 5"/>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                        ... <!-- more ColumnListItems -->
                    </items>
                </Table>
            </ScrollContainer>
        </content>
    </Panel>
</mvc:View>

Unfortunately, in my experience, using a sap.m.ScrollContainer for this purpose only works if the height is not dynamic, i.e. you have to specify a fixed height for the sap.m.ScrollContainer, otherwise the sticky-property (of the sap.m.Table) is not taken into account.
The use of viewport units (vh, etc.) is also not possible in my case.
Here are some more screenshots to help you understand.
ScrollContainer with fixed height (column headers are still displayed at the top when scrolling):

ScrollContainer with dynamic height (not scrolled yet):

ScrollContainer with dynamic height (when scrolling):

Do you have any ideas how to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance.
